# Sharing external SDK binaries to WPF and Silverlight

Tags: wpf, silverlight, sdk, compatibility

I've been trying to sort this out for some time now..

I have a few .NET libraries that work as an SDK to an external application. I need to use that SDK both from a WPF Class Library and a Silverlight Class Library. I've been reading a lot of solutions including:

- Portable Class Libraries - When I try to add the SDK libraries to the project, it complains that those libraries reference .NET 2.0 libraries and it is incompatible.
- WCF RIA - I may be doing this wrong, but everywhere I turn, one step of the process is to create an Entity with the EF. Now, I don't want to access a DB, just those libraries.

But so far, no luck. Any ideas you would like to share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, it may not work if the old .NET 2.0 binaries have references to COM or system libraries. That could relate to your DB implementation. I have had this problem in a project in a previous job. We solved this by creating a WCF service as a in-between solution. That was WCF and not WCF RIA.

If the .NET 2.0 code is really old, you should check if it must be compiled as x86 and hosted as a 32-bits application on AppPool of the site that hosts the WCF service in the IIS.

But this is tricky business, and it all depends on the complexity of the old .NET 2.0 library file and its references.

Comment: I think this solved my issue. At least I'm now able to compile all the components. I'm still struggling with referencing the WCF service from the consumer Silverlight. But I think that it's just a matter of time.

Comment: What errors do you get from Silverlight when trying toconnect to the WCF service? CrossDomain issues are easy to fix. And it also depends a little on the endpoint type.

Comment: My issue is actually deploying the WCF service itself. I can't do it manually, i just add the library to a pack, import it to a third party software, and I'm trying to figure out how to make it deploy either as a service, WAS, IIS...

Comment: I have good experience hosting WCF services from a Windows Service. That way, you can deploy it with a MSI and make other install-specific configuration (address etc) from that same MSI or from a config app you create with the package.
Hosting WCF is not hard, but it's in my experience a little time-demanding at first.
A hint for starting is here :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx